# Raspberry Pi Zero get 5 V directly from the input

Tags: pi-zero-w, gpiozero

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero and I would like a tiny fan which draws 90 mA.

Obviously, I can't connect it to the GPIO pins and therefore I need to get 5 V from the input cable.

Before I start cutting the cable open, is there any pin that connects directly to the 5 V rail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two pins (2 and 4) on the gpio connector that carry the 5V supply voltage. See [official schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-V1.3-Schematics.pdf) - look for J8 - or any of the gazillion websites showing Raspberry Pi pinouts.